# If gravity on a non-rotating body suddenly stopped, would an object on the surface fly away?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

This is a very trivial question, and I tried to word the title as concisely as possible, but I can't seem to figure it out. This is not referring to any hypothetical discussions regarding Earth.

Consider a body such as a perfectly spherical planet that does not rotate. On its surface is a small ball. Obviously as the ball rests on the surface it is experiencing a resistant force equal to the gravitational force of the planet. If gravitational forces were suddenly removed, would the ball remain on the surface or be ejected from the planet with a force equal to the former gravity?

Comment: It will remain there as a direct consequence of inertia of rest. Is their any repelling force you find?

Comment: If it or the surface it is sitting on is elastic, then they could spring apart.  I believe that this possible effect was the subject of the question.

Comment: @DuncanHarris Sorry, I forgot to mention the assumption that both objects are completely rigid, but that is a good point.

Comment: @tom10 The scenario is specifically regarding a non-rotating body.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (ie, restatement of what's obvious in your question... I just missed it).  I see now why it was closed... the answer to this will depend entirely on the details of the hypothetical you've set up, and since it's hypothetical, it's impossible to guess at those details.

Comment: @tom10 Do you really need more parameters than rotation and structural rigidity? I'm not asking for a measure of the force, simply if the force would exist in that moment.

Comment: @tom10 I wasn't expecting any discussion. I thought I could ask a simple question and get a simple answer. Why would I change the question when that is what I'm seeking to answer to?